# How to create suitability map from categorical raster and Euclidean distance raster in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, spatial-analyst, suitability-analysis

If I want to create a suitability model for site location based on soil drainage and proximity to water features, what tool would I use? As well, would there be a way to add in a third raster if I wanted to use slope as a factor as well?

[image: Distance Raster]

[image: Categorical Raster]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [detailed documentation](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/analytics/case-studies/understanding-the-suitability-modeling-workflow.htm) on esri's site outlining the process of suitability modeling. Suitability modeling is an iterative process. As such it can be beneficial to set the process(es) up in model builder. This allows you to make changes and rerun the process rather than manually repeating the workflow.

It looks like you are are working with raster data and have defined the problem and identified the criteria. The next stage would be to transform each raster to a comparable scale (say 1-10, 1 being undesirable, 10 being desirable). You can do this using the [Reclassify Raster tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/reclassify.htm) available with the Spatial Analyst extension.

Having reclassified your rasters you can then add weights (importance) to each input using the [weighted overlay tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/weighted-overlay.htm). Again this is available with the Spatial Analyst extension.

Comment: Thanks, I got a beautiful raster. 
So, for this output, the correct interpretation is the same as the inputs, correct? (1 still being the most favorable and 9 being the least)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZc3C.png

Comment: It depends on how you have reclassified your rasters. It's common for high scores to win (high value = most suitable, low value = least suitable). Make sure all your input rasters follow the same criteria whether it be high scores win or low scores win.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with what [@Oliver Burdekin has mentioned](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/431138/107424). As suitability modelling is an iterative process and you start off with applying a set of weights for each raster layer, you could extend this to cover a sensitivity analysis. In other words, play around with the weights to get what you think is an ideal output, perhaps reading the literature for some inspiration might help here.